# Error on greenfoot, "illegal start of expression"

Tags: java, greenfoot

Whenever I hit compile it says illegal start of expression wherever private is located. Here is the code:

```
    /**
     * Act - do whatever the PlatformJumper wants to do. This method is called whenever
     * the 'Act' or 'Run' button gets pressed in the environment.
     */
    public void act() 
    {
        if(inTheAir)
        {
            fall();
        } else {
            getCommand();
        }
        move();

        if(isTouching(snowball.class))
        {
            get (snowball.class);
        }    

    private void run (String direction)
    {
        if(direction=="left")
            deltaX = walkSpeed*-1;
        else
            deltaX = walkSpeed;
    }

    private void stop ()
    {
        deltaX = 0;
    }

    private void jump()
    {
        deltaY += jumpHeight;
        inTheAir = true;
    }

    /*
     * fall() will be called whenever BallGuy is in the air. Decreases the deltaY by 1, creating
     * gravity.
     */
    private void fall()
    {
        deltaY-=fallSpeed;
    }

    private void move()
    {
        double newX = getX() + deltaX;
        double newY = getY() - deltaY;

        Actor platformBelow = getOneObjectAtOffset(0, groundHeight + 5, Platform.class);
        Actor platformAbove = getOneObjectAtOffset(0, -(groundHeight + 5), Platform.class);
        Actor platformToRight = getOneObjectAtOffset(sideWidth+5, 0, Platform.class);
        Actor platformToLeft = getOneObjectAtOffset(-(sideWidth+5), 0, Platform.class);
        if(platformBelow!=null)
        {
            if(deltaY<0)
            {
                deltaY = 0;
                inTheAir = false;
                GreenfootImage platformImage = platformBelow.getImage();
                int topOfPlatform = platformBelow.getY() - platformImage.getHeight()/2;
                newY = topOfPlatform - groundHeight;
            }
        }else if(getY() >= worldHeight - groundHeight) {
            if(deltaY < 0)
            {
                deltaY = 0;
                inTheAir = false;
                newY = worldHeight - groundHeight;
            }
        } else {
            inTheAir = true;
        }
        if(platformAbove != null)
        {
            if(deltaY>0)
            {
                deltaY=0;

                GreenfootImage platformImage = platformAbove.getImage();
                int bottomOfPlatform = platformAbove.getY() + platformImage.getHeight()/2;
                newY = bottomOfPlatform + groundHeight;
            }
        }
        if(getX()<=sideWidth)
        {
            deltaX = Math.abs(deltaX);
        }
        if(getX()>=worldWidth-sideWidth)
        {
            deltaX = Math.abs(deltaX) * -1;
        }
        if(platformToRight!=null)
        {
            deltaX = Math.abs(deltaX) * -1;
        }
        if(platformToLeft!=null)
        {
            deltaX = Math.abs(deltaX);
        }
        setLocation((int)newX,(int)newY);
    }

    private void getCommand()
    {
        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("left"))
        {
            run("left");
        } else if (Greenfoot.isKeyDown("right"))
        {
            run("right");
        } else 
        {
            stop();
        }

        if(Greenfoot.isKeyDown("up"))
        {
            jump();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the top of your class definition, and as you have no `main` method, how is the program running?

Comment: Is it possible to edit the question a little bit so the code is in the code box and the question itself is a little bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

```
import greenfoot.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class BallGuy here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class BallGuy extends
{
    public BallGuy()
    {
    }
```

There should be something that looks like this at the top of your code. Right now the compiler thinks there are extra brackets at the bottom of the code. I'm presuming you left that out for the question.

ALSO:

Add a bracket on the line above the first private method. The act() method isn't closed.

```
public void act() 
    {
        if(inTheAir)
        {
            fall();
        } else {
            getCommand();
        }
        move();

        if(isTouching(snowball.class))
        {
            get (snowball.class);
        }    
    }

private void run (String direction)
{
    if(direction=="left")
        deltaX = walkSpeed*-1;
    else
        deltaX = walkSpeed;
}
```

Like that.